# How to add Amazon Ads in my Android application

Tags: android, admob, amazon-advertising-api

Today and I don't know how (And I actually I don't care) my AdMob account has been suspended for a month, it was a long email to share, but somehow I felt like I'm a thug or criminal who want to steal their money (Which was less than a dollar as my app just got published a couple of days ago), perhaps there was a mistake from my side (The only thing comes in my mind that I may forgot to disable the live Ads while testing my code today as a result of publishing an update that fixes a bug).

Anyway, they will not serve me any Ads for a month, and as there was no even a warning and no appealing, I'm considering to use Amazon Ads in my app.

My question is,

1- Is it easy to implement an Amazon ad banner in my code?

2- Do I have to publish my application on Amazon App Store too?

3- Is there a step by step guide to implement Amazon ad in my code?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1- Is it easy to implement an Amazon ad banner in my code?

Totally depends on your expertise level. But, even if you are moderately comfortable with android development and have worked on integration with other ad networks it should not be hard at all.

> 2- Do I have to publish my application on Amazon App Store too?

No, but it is recommended to do so. What the harm in having an additional distribution channel? It will only do you good by bringing in more downloads.

The getting started page clearly states this: `Submit your app to the Amazon Appstore, Google Play, **or** another app distribution framework`. Hence publishing on Amazon is not a mandate.

You will have to sign the [MOBILE AD NETWORK PUBLISHER AGREEMENT](https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/mobileads/publisher-agreement.html)

> 3- Is there a step by step guide to implement Amazon ad in my code?

Yes, refer the [official documentation here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-ads/android)

[These FAQs](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-ads/docs/faq) will help you better understand each of the points you've put in your question.

And why only amazon as an alternative? You have [a whole lot of other options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12934810/1957401).

Comment: Thank you, that's really appreciated :)

Comment: Actually I was about to ask you what do you recommend other than AdMob, I only know AdMob (A week ago), and Amazon and also Facebook ads, I don't know which one is best choice, for me I consider the one that pays me for showing ads in my app (I only use one bottom banner ad to keep my application looks clean) not based on the number of clicks .. I will check your alternative link and thank you for your help ... it comforts me.